# Can you put admob interstitial reward ads id in place of normal interstitial ads?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, admob

My question is whether I can place interstitial reward ads, where ordinary interstitial ads are provided... If I created a "fake reward" of course, but would Admob notice? The type of application is a game.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No, Reward Ads can be as long as 15 to 30 seconds, whereas an Interstitial can be skippable after a maximum of 4/5 seconds. Rewarded Ads are used to obviously provide something in return for the user something (probably allowing access to a premium feature for free, game coins, or whatever) whereas Interstitial has no such requirement.